# How can I move all files from one folder to another? GCP, cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I need to move exactly all files from one folder in cloud storage to another, how can I do it? I have seen gsutil command, but I cannot find how to move all files.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A folder in a storage bucket is just a prefix (see [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cloud-console#_creatingfolders)).

So, what you want to do is change the prefix and according to GCS [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv#renaming-groups-of-objects), what you need is

```
    gsutil mv gs://my_bucket/oldprefix gs://my_bucket/newprefix
```